# Refreshing listview with custom auto-dividers

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to use jquery mobile with knockout.js to create a simple application based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975345.aspx). I've a listview with custom auto-dividers. The listview is created by knockoutjs. I'm trying to enhance the listview once the templating is over.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRefreshList = {
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //just to create a dependency
    $(element).listview({
      autodividers: true,
      autodividersSelector: function (li) {
        var out = li.data("group");
        return out;
      }
    }).listview("refresh");
  }
};

  <div data-role="content">
    <ul id="secretlist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-bind="template: { name: 'someTpl', foreach: todos }, jqmRefreshList: todos" data-autodividers="true">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is throwing a javascript error. I even tried using try..catch as demonstrated [here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/10/23/integrating-knockout-and-jquerymobile.html) with no luck. Any idea how to solve this issue? I see there are problems on integrating jquery mobile with knockoutjs. Is there any MV* framework that is easy to use with jqm?

Comment: "This is throwing a javascript error." What is the error? Can you maybe create a JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem?